# Because when I run keytool fill all fields and keep asking me back

Tags: keytool

Because when I run keytool in cmf.exe fill all fields and keep asking me back

keytool -genkey -v -keystore [keystore_name].keystore -alias [alias_name] -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

Do not generate the keystore, after asking if everything is correct, and I put yes becomes responsive again. Because? I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is going wrong for you. And it works for me.

Try giving all the parameters in one go, like this :

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore test.jks -alias test
>   -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -storepass test-keypass test-dname "CN=test.com,OU=Test,O=Test,L=Test,S=Test,C=Test"

This should store the keystore without prompting for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I realized that it was because of my OS language (I have spanish by default), so when I answered with "si" it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).